Prove that an inverse limit of arcs, as well as an inverse limit of simple closed curves cannot contain a simple triod.
I found this question in chapter 2 of Nadler's Introduction to Continuum theory but I'm a bit lost on how to prove this. I've already searched this question and I found that an inverse limit of arcs is an arc and an inverse limit of simple closed curves is a simple closed curve, however I didn't found proof of any of this.
I tried to prove directly that if $\{X_i,f_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ are the elements of an inverse sequence with inverse limit $X_\infty$, then there must exist an homeomorphism $h:[0,1]\rightarrow X_\infty$. I tried to define this function by first noting that $f_i(X_{i+1})$ is an arc, so there must exist an homeomorphism $h_i:[0,1] \rightarrow f(X_{i+1})$, so with this in mind my idea for the definition of $h$ is $h(t) = (h_i(t))_{i=1}^\infty$. However I'm struggling in how to prove that this function is well defined. To see that it is well defined, we need that $f_i(h_{i+1}(t)) = h_i(t)$ for every $i$ and every $t$. I know that because of how I took the functions $h_i$ that there exists some $t_1$ such that $f_i(h_{i+1}(t)) = h_i(t_1)$, however this doesn't really solve my problem, so any help with this would be greately apreciated.

First of all it is not true in general that an inverse limit of arcs is an arc (it is true if the maps in the inverse sequence are monotone though).
Here's a big hint for the exercise, let me know if you need further help. Seeing where the exercise is in Nadler's book you're probably meant to use the easy part of Theorem 2.13 to solve this exercise. Suppose that $X=\varprojlim X_i$ with $X_i\simeq [0,1]$ for all $i$, then by 2.13 we have that $X$ is arc-like, that is for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is an $\varepsilon$-map $f\colon X\to[0,1]$.
Now suppose that $T$ is a triod, is there any $\varepsilon$-map from $T$ to $[0,1]$ when $\varepsilon$ is sufficiently small compared to the length of the arms of the triod? What does that imply for $X$, can it contain a triod?
In the second case an inverse limit of simple closed curves is circle-like, once again think about $\varepsilon$-maps from $T$ to $S^1$.
